# Creating a windows Installer for a web app (laragon/laravel)

Tags: windows, laravel, windows-installer, laragon

I made a web app in Laravel that runs exclusively on Windows, and will be deployed individually on end users machines, I was wondering where i would start making an installer that would :

- download and configure Laragon
- transfer my app to the relevant place
- initialise mysql
- run artisan commands.

Ive considered using something like wix but It looks like it has a pretty steep learning curve.

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble but Laragon is just a webserver. Your laravel application is written with PHP which runs on apache servers. So your laravel app is not exclusivlye for Windows in fact it won't even work on Windows by itself. You need a server.

Comment: No bubble to burst mate, I realise its a web server - i need an installer that will install the 'webserver' and my 'php scripts' onto end users machines who will exclusively have windows and no knowledge of these things - The php scripts use COM therefore REALLY EXCLUSIVELY windows - thanks for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laragon is very portable, you just simply zip it and send to your customers.
Let me explain:

```
1. You installed Laragon in your machine C:\laragon
2. You created a Laravel app name: awesomeapp. There should be a folder name C:\laragon\www\awesomeapp
3. The correspond database will be stored in C:\laragon\data....
```

Just zip it to laragon.zip (or laragon.tar.gz for better compression), then your customers can extract to C:\laragon or D:\laragon or E:\yourcompany\laragon,... no matter what.

He just run laragon.exe and click Start All button. After a while, he can browser http://awesomeapp.dev and use your app.

**Note:**

1. Your customers may use Skype which usually bind to port 80 & 443, so
   instruct them to unbind the ports
2. You can instruct your customers to set Laragon to start with Windows and automatically run all services + Minimize Laragon to
   system tray. So, when start their computers, they can use your app
   without doing anything.

Source: https://forum.laragon.org/topic/73/windows-installer

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Im going going to give it a go and get back to you

Comment: So that worked - I used Inno setup to package all of the files in c:\laragon and then made a post install script that changed the domain name (using user input) - one thing i did have to work out was installing VC++ redistributable packages using Inno setup (laragon doesn't work without 2012 and 2015)

Comment: Ah i just realised that was my question at https://forum.laragon.org/topic/73/windows-installer :)